# Scala Application runs perfectly in Eclipse IDE but running a jar of the same code from terminal gives OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, jar, out-of-memory

Scala Application when run in Eclipse IDE terminates with the desired result in 27 seconds,

but running a jar of the same code from terminal gives:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-vmargs
-Xmx2G
-Xms200m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

Command I'm using to run the jar file:

```
scala variance-withoutRowLimit.jar -Xms512m -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

Comment: The 'eclipse.ini' settings are nothing to do with the memory used when you run a program from within Eclipse - those are specified in the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog.

Comment: @greg-449 yes I know. Just wanted make the heap size values clear.
Tho can you specify where in Run  Configurations I can tweak memory values, can't find where

Comment: Have you tried without the `-XX:MaxPermSize` option?

Comment: @GregHNZ yes! Facing same problem